# Can I delete an object of a model from view even though the user doesn't have permission? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a model X, now created a user U, I assigned a group to this user G, G has only create and change permissions for the model X, Now I created a view where it lists all model X objects and delete button across each object, now when I am logging in with my user U, he can access that view( I am not restricting him here )  and he is able to delete that object from that model? Is it how it works? I need to restrict him from view too as well as at user permission level(groups)?

Comment: Permissions only apply to Django admin, not to your views unless you specifically check for them.

Comment: @Selcuk I see, Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the admin page or custom view ? Permissions only work for admin page. For limiting permission on a custom view, you need to add custom logic.